# The truth table of implication

Tags: logic

I can't understand the truth table of implication

I could understand that 
'if p then q' : true     then

'if p then not q': false

But why

'if not p then q' and 'if not p then not q' are true?

I thought that they can be true and false depending on the situation.

But why are they both true?

Comment: You may also be interested in my recent blog posting on Material Implication.  There, I effectively derive, among other things, the entire truth table for IMPLIES using only self-evident, elementary properties of logical implication. http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html

Comment: The part you said you "could understand" is wrong. When p is false then both "if p then q" and "if p then not q" are true.